# JIRA JQL Query - Results

Tags: python, jira, jql

I'm writing a JQL query to fetch only Service Requests. I'm not able to fetch the Service Request field name from the below json using JQL Query. Any help will be appreciated

'jql': 'key=ITSM-1917' => This is working .. But I'm trying to fetch based on issuetype.name='Service Request'

```
{'expand': 'names,schema', 'startAt': 0, 'maxResults': 100, 'total': 1, 'issues': [{'expand': 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', 'id': '373234', 'self': '', 'key': 'ITSM-1917', 'fields': {'issuetype': {'self': '', 'id': '10300', 'description': 'Created by JIRA Service Desk.', 'iconUrl': '', '**name': 'Service Request**', 'subtask': False, 'avatarId': 11006}, 'assignee': {'self': '', 'name': 'IT Service Management', 'key': 'JIRAUSER10945', 'emailAddress': '', 'avatarUrls': {'48x48': 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/067a17d84b041546f0f658bd011bc3ba?d=mm&s=48', '24x24': 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/067a17d84b041546f0f658bd011bc3ba?d=mm&s=24', '16x16': 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/067a17d84b041546f0f658bd011bc3ba?d=mm&s=16', '32x32': 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/067a17d84b041546f0f658bd011bc3ba?d=mm&s=32'}, 'displayName': 'IT Service Management', 'active': True, 'timeZone': 'America/New_York'}, 'created': '2022-11-23T01:34:11.000-0500', 'status': {'self': '', 'description': 'A resolution has been taken, and it is awaiting verification by reporter. From here issues are either reopened, certified, or are closed.', 'iconUrl': '', 'name': 'Resolved', 'id': '5', 'statusCategory': {'self': '', 'id': 3, 'key': 'done', 'colorName': 'green', 'name': 'Done'}}}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following JQL instead:

```
issuetype = "Service Request"
```

Please check the [Jira search documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver/advanced-searching-939938733.html). If you meant anything else, be more specific.